# How do I comment a publicly visible type Enum?

Tags: c#, enums, comments

How do I comment this Enum so that the warning does not appear? Yes I realize that comments are unnecessary, but if commenting is easy and it resolves the warnings then I'd like to do it.

Warnings that appear:
Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member

```
/// <summary>
/// Conditional statements
/// </summary>
public enum ConditionType
{
    Equal,
    NotEqual,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqual,
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqual
}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Conditional statements
/// </summary>
public enum ConditionType
{
    ///<summary>A == B</summary>
    Equal,
    ///<summary>A != B</summary>
    NotEqual,
    ///<summary>A > B</summary>
    GreaterThan,
    ///<summary>A >= B</summary>
    GreaterThanOrEqual,
    ///<summary>A < B</summary>
    LessThan,
    ///<summary>A <= B</summary>
    LessThanOrEqual
}
```

(Yes, this can get very tedious)

You may want to use different texts in the comments.

By the way. your enum should actually be called `ComparisonType`.

Comment: Upvoted for the ComparisonType, this is really important!

Comment: can the summary value be obtained programmatically while looping through the enum values?

Comment: @DanHastings: These values only exist in the XML doc comments file, if you tell the compiler to create one.

Answer (score 20):

Comment each member:

```
/// <summary>
/// Conditional statements
/// </summary>
public enum ConditionType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for equality
    /// </summary>
    Equal,
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for inequality
    /// </summary>
    NotEqual,
    // etc..
}
```

You may also want to check out [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/download/ghostdoc/) for easy commenting